# What engine to use for Android ball game?

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I want develop a very simple android game, the main idea is to throw a ball to some target,  something like basketball/football.

It should be in 3d like the famous "Paper Toss" 
(https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bfs.papertoss&feature=search_result)

what engine I should use? I read about many engines but it seems that most of them for more complex things.

Or maybe it would be enoughto use OpenGl ??

Comment: Welcome to SO! Questions of the form "what X should I use/choose" and "give me a list of Y" aren't considered constructive here. Could you be more specific about your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of game engines you could use. Two popular engines are:

- [Libdgx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/)
- [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/)

AndEngine is simpler and probably easier to get started on. Libgdx allows you to produce cross platform games that can be run under Linux and Windows.

I would actually suggest you get the book [Beginning Android Games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230428) . It was written by the guy who made Libgdx and its walks you through the process of building an implementing a simple engine from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i read that the AndEngine is 2d engine or maybe i wrong ?

Comment: yes AndEngine is a 2D engine, but games like Paper Toss are 2D as well.